# Basic jquery slider - images not showing when integrated to website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-slider

I put a Basic jquery slider on my website, but the images just do not show up. The slider worked perfectly when I tried it on a page of its own, but when integrated to my website it just does not display the images. The images are on the server just fine, and if I inspect the element and then close the "inspection window", all of a sudden the slider works, but when downloaded normally on a browser it just doesn't.

I have run out of ideas as I am not a developer as such, and know very little about javascript, but I understand it probably is just a little integration problem. If anyone, who has more experience could spot it, I would be more than grateful.

Here is the URL, look for GALLERIA section: 
http://www.oksalonkihoitohuone.fi

To  find it when inspecting element: 
ApDiv1, TabbedPanelsContentGroup, TabbedPanelsContent TabbedPanelsContentVisible

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the script at the very bottom of the page. I mean just before the closing tag of the body. Right now, there are several other images before that. I know that your slider initialization code is wrapped in *.ready* handler, but it helps sometimes.

The thing which you use for switching the page may also be the problem. Try showing the gallery first and see if that changes something.

Put your styles in separate stylesheet. Adding styles directly into the page is not a good practice.

Comment: That's great, but doesn't fix the problem. Because I guess you will have another tab as a first page. However, this proves that maybe the problem is in the code which switches the tabs.

Comment: Yes this is true. It's a dreamweaver tabbed panel. I guess they just didn't expect anyone to put a jquery slider in...